Estimate max number of lattice points on a circle's circumference.
Notes
Theorem 1.2 states

An arc of length $(16R)^{1/3}$ on a circle of radius R centered at the
origin contains no more than two lattice points.


Claim
The max number of lattice points on a circle's circumference are $$2^{2/3} \cdot \pi \cdot R^{2/3}$$
Proof
Let $C = 2\pi R$ be the circumference of a circle with radius $R$.
\begin{align}
\text{Number of arcs} & = \frac{C}{(16R)^{1/3}} 
= \frac{2\pi R}{(16R)^{1/3}} 
= \frac{\pi R^{2/3}}{2^{1/3}} \\
\end{align}
From Theorem 1.2, each arc can contain at most $2$ lattice points, so
\begin{align}
\text{Max lattice points} & \leq 2 \cdot \frac{\pi R^{2/3}}{2^{1/3}}  = 2^{2/3} \cdot \pi \cdot R^{2/3} \text{ } \blacksquare \\
\end{align}
Question
Is the proof valid and is there a more refined upper bound for the number of lattice points on a circle's circumference?
